”I am very proud to say we’re sorry“, why proud instead of ashamed?
I read (re-read) Gordon Brown's apology for treatment of Alan Turing and I am still struck by these words:

“So on behalf of the British government, and all those who live freely
thanks to Alan’s work I am very proud to say: we’re sorry, you
deserved so much better."

"I am very proud to say: we’re sorry" ?! Shouldn't he say "I am very ashamed to say: we’re sorry, you deserved so much better".  Is this a culture thing ?
BTW, this happened in 2009 but my recent question to another word usage brought it back to me.

He was proud of Turing's work. I guess Brown was aiming at some kind of rhetorical paradox, assuming the transcription is correct - have you attempted to find a recording of Brown's speech? This question isn't really about English language (and it doesn't show any attempt to solve the question using the standard methods for understanding English) but it might belong on writing SE if the quote is accurate.

The "we" here is complicated. He's apologizing for things done in the past by his predecessors, and he's quite proud of himself for being so generous as to make the apology. So "we," the British government at large, "are sorry," but "I," Gordon Brown, "am proud" that we can say so.

I don't think it has any special meaning. He's just expressing that he feels grateful or satisfied in giving this apology, since he sees it as righting a past injustice. He didn't perpetrate that injustice, so he'd have no reason to be ashamed. (Possibly also a reference to "gay pride," given the context.)

In other words, he's ashamed they persecuted Turing, but proud that they've learned better and are willing to apologize now.

The term 'weasel words' sadly springs to mind. I remember Mycroft in Sherlock, brought to task by Sherlock and John Watson after he made a cutting remark to Mrs Hudson, managing "Apologies" rather than "I apologise" or "Please forgive me". Brown is arguably attempting to hunt with the hounds and run with the hare. // Then again, I'd say it's nigh impossible to apologise for the actions of predecessors you believe to have done wrong. Especially without (here) tarnishing the whole political structure of the country. I'm not sure what Gordon Brown could have said.

This is a one-off attempt at being subtle and original. Whether it is successful is debatable. Mr Bonner's comment correctly states the intention behind it, but, as it is does not exhibit a repeatable feature of English Language and usage, posting that analysis in a formal answer would be out of place on this site.

I’m voting to close this question because I don't think there's any question about English here. He's using the word "proud" in the ordinary sense of the word; explaining why he feels that way isn't a question about the language.
